# how to copy files from a folder and also files in sub folder in powershell script

Tags: powershell, nuget-package

How to copy files of type .txt from a folder and its sub folder using powershell script. If the file I subfolder I want the subfolder as well copied to the destination.  Thanks

I tried the following

```
Copy-item c:\tes\* *.txt c:\dest -recurse -force
```

This copies only files froom root folder and not from subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best solution but it should work:

I use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to filter all `*.txt`files, determine the new path, creating the new directory using [md](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293886) and finally copy the files using the [Copy-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113292) cmdlet:

```
$source = 'D:\test1'
$destination = 'D:\test2'

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *.txt -Recurse | % {
 $newDirectory = Join-Path $destination ($_.DirectoryName.Substring($source.Length))
  md $newDirectory -Force | out-null
  Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $newDirectory
 }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. Will this command create the directory if it already exists?

Comment: It just ensures that the directory exists. You can also wrap it into a `Test-Path` if you want to but this should always work too.